# Misspelling instructions when migrating from BouncyCastle bcprov-jdk15on 1.62 to v1.69

Tags: java, cryptography, bouncycastle, pki

I got a Java application which is using BouncyCastle bcprov-jdk15on version 1.62. I'll show the following source code:

Pom file:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
        <artifactId>bcprov-jdk15on</artifactId>
        <version>1.62</version>    
        <scope>provided</scope>   
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

CSR.java

```
import org.bouncycastle.asn1.DEROutputStream;
    
...

public String createSigningRequest(String signAlgorithm, String subject, PublicKey publicKey, PrivateKey privateKey, String provName) {
    StringBuilder sb = null;
    try {
                                    sb      = new StringBuilder();
        X509Name                    xname   = new X509Name(subject);
        PKCS10CertificationRequest  csr     = new PKCS10CertificationRequest(signAlgorithm, xname, publicKey , null, privateKey, provName);
        ByteArrayOutputStream       baos    = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        DEROutputStream             deros   = new DEROutputStream(baos);
        deros.writeObject(csr.toASN1Primitive());
        String                      sTmp    = new String(org.bouncycastle.util.encoders.Base64.encode(baos.toByteArray()));
        
        sb.append(HEADER_CSR_PEM);
        for (int iCnt=0; iCnt < sTmp.length(); iCnt+=CERT_REQ_LINE_LENGTH) {
            int iLineLength;
            if ((iCnt + CERT_REQ_LINE_LENGTH) > sTmp.length()) {
                iLineLength=sTmp.length() - iCnt;
            }
            else {
                iLineLength=CERT_REQ_LINE_LENGTH;
            }
            sb.append(sTmp.substring(iCnt,iCnt + iLineLength)).append("\n");
        }
        sb.append(FOOTER_CSR_PEM);
        return sb.toString();
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException | NoSuchProviderException | InvalidKeyException | SignatureException | IOException ex) {
        errorMessage = ex.getLocalizedMessage();
        LOG.error("createSigningRequest : " + ex.getLocalizedMessage());
    }

    return "";
}
```

On the other side, there are BouncyCastle bcprov-jdk15on 1.69 from Maven repository. So I upgraded the pom file with this new version. Even though, I have the following misspelling instructions:

```
import org.bouncycastle.asn1.DEROutputStream;  //DEROutputStream is not public in org.bouncycastle.asn1; cannot be accessed from outside package
...
DEROutputStream             deros   = new DEROutputStream(baos);   //DEROutputStream is not public in org.bouncycastle.asn1; cannot be accessed from outside package
...
} catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException | NoSuchProviderException | InvalidKeyException | SignatureException | IOException ex) {   //exception IOException is never thrown in body of corresponding try statement
```

These three instruccions are not recognized. My question is what are the new instructions in order to change according to bcprov-jdk15on 1.69?

- Added: "Error when I deploy to Wildfly 10 with jdk 1.8u341"

I get the following error:

```
Cannot upload deployment: 
{"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => 
    {"jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./myJavaApp" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./myJavaApp: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 51201 
        Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 51201"},
    "WFLYCTL0412: Required services that are not installed:" => ["jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./myJavaApp"],
    "WFLYCTL0180: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => undefined}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the [documentation of `DEROutputStream`](https://javadoc.io/static/org.bouncycastle/bcprov-jdk15on/1.66/org/bouncycastle/asn1/DEROutputStream.html) then you can read the following text for the constructor (I've pointed to 1.66 but this is already in 1.64 as well and possibly before):

> **Deprecated.** Use [`ASN1OutputStream.create(OutputStream, String)`](https://javadoc.io/static/org.bouncycastle/bcprov-jdk15on/1.66/org/bouncycastle/asn1/ASN1OutputStream.html#create-java.io.OutputStream-java.lang.String-) with [`ASN1Encoding.DER`](https://javadoc.io/static/org.bouncycastle/bcprov-jdk15on/1.66/org/bouncycastle/asn1/ASN1Encoding.html#DER) instead.

Yes, the changes to the lightweight API of Bouncy are a bit of an annoyance, and the entire class should probably have been deprecated.

Comment: I was making testing about you said. My netbeans is associated to jdk 1.8u341. I change it toANS1OutputStream in source code. Then I was debugging and I see it works in my PC. Even though, I couldn't deploy the app on test server with Wildfly 10 with Java 1.8u341. I'll write the error in the Post above as Added: "Error when I deploy to Wildfly 10 with jdk 1.8u341"